# Determining the type of objects in a collection or array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Suppose I have an array int[][] or an array char[][] or an ArrayList. Is there a way in java to know the base class type of the array. For Example:

```
int[][] gives output as int.
char[][] gives output as char.
ArrayList<Integer> gives output Integer.
ArrayList<Point> gives Point. (It should also work for a custom type)
```

Can this be done in Java?

Comment: `ArrayList<int>` is wrong , must be `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: Don't know how he got that to "compile"

Comment: It is not a code so it won't compile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Arrays** (e.g. `int[][]`)

You can get the array's component type using [getComponentType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29):

```
(new int[10][10]).getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType(); // int
```

For arrays of arbitrary depth use a loop:

```
Object array = new int[10][][][];
Class<?> type = array.getClass();
while (type.isArray())
{
    type = type.getComponentType();
}
assert type == Integer.TYPE;
```

**Generic Types** (e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>`)

It is not possible to get the type parameter. Java uses [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so the information is lost at runtime.

You can guess the declared type of collections based on the types of the elements:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CollectionTypeGuesser
{
    static Set<Class<?>> supers(Class<?> c)
    {
        if (c == null) return new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        Set<Class<?>> s = supers(c.getSuperclass());
        s.add(c);
        return s;
    }

    static Class<?> lowestCommonSuper(Class<?> a, Class<?> b)
    {
        Set<Class<?>> aSupers = supers(a);
        while (!aSupers.contains(b))
        {
            b = b.getSuperclass();
        }
        return b;
    }

    static Class<?> guessElementType(Collection<?> collection)
    {
        Class<?> guess = null;
        for (Object o : collection)
        {
            if (o != null)
            {
                if (guess == null)
                {
                    guess = o.getClass();
                }
                else if (guess != o.getClass())
                {
                    guess = lowestCommonSuper(guess, o.getClass());
                }
            }
        }
        return guess;
    }

    static class C1 { }
    static class C2 extends C1 { }
    static class C3A extends C2 { }
    static class C3B extends C2 { }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> listOfInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println(guessElementType(listOfInt)); // null
        listOfInt.add(42);
        System.out.println(guessElementType(listOfInt)); // Integer

        ArrayList<C1> listOfC1 = new ArrayList<C1>();
        listOfC1.add(new C3A());
        System.out.println(guessElementType(listOfC1)); // C3A
        listOfC1.add(new C3B());
        System.out.println(guessElementType(listOfC1)); // C2
        listOfC1.add(new C1());
        System.out.println(guessElementType(listOfC1)); // C1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the classes `getComponentType()`. For example.

```
public static final Class<?> getBaseType(Object obj) {
    Class<?> type = obj.getClass();
    while (type.isArray()) {
        type = type.getComponentType();
    }
    return type;
}
```

`type` will then be whatever the base type is.

This will work if `obj` is `double[][][][][][]` or just `double[]`, or something else.

As for generics, those things in `<` and `>`. Type erasure occurs, meaning you cannot determine what type those are from the `ArrayList` itself.

Comment: Looks like tom borrowed my answer and incorporated it into his own. :)

Comment: Only for completeness -- I hope you don't mind. And anyway, wasn't it I who suggested using `isArray()`?

Comment: Of course, I didn't mind. I just found it interesting. I did write the  rest of it though, and my way to determine if it was an array also worked.

Answer (score 2):

In case of arrays, it can be identified via the type of an `array`, (e.g. `array` of `int[][]` will always give you `int`.

In case of `ArrayList`, if your `ArrayList` is heterogeneous objects then, `get(i)` will always give you the element of type `Object`. To know its class, you can use `getClass()` method of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Following code works...as you asked..

Here, I have used

> object.getClass().getSimpleName()

for arraylist you must add an item of specific type since you are using generics. and then get them and have it use same getClass().getSimpleName() method.

```
  public class ShowObjectType {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int arr[][] = { { 2, 3 }, { 4, 0 } };
            char[][] arr1 = { { 'a', 'c' }, { 'b', 'd' } };
            ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            arr2.add(4);
            ArrayList<Point> arr3 = new ArrayList<Point>();
            arr3.add(new Point());
            System.out.println(arr.getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.out.println(arr1.getClass().getSimpleName());
                System.out.println(arr2.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.out.println(arr3.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    class Point {

    }
```

hope it helps

Comment: This is is the easier way you can achieve what you have asked for.

Comment: @tom I know it won't work with generic types with Empty Collections. But here asked question was about this only...so i have given kind of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are called Generics. But is better to think that it forces the Arraylist to only hold "point" objects.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

1. Use the `instanceof` operator.
2. Call `getClass()` on the object (make sure to check for null first).

For this you can also refer which i found:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get base type of Array as:

```
Object obj = new Long[0];
Class ofArray = obj.getClass().getComponentType();
```

For Collection type, you can use the getClass() method, or you can use instanceof. For example:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = ...;

for (Object obj : list) {
   if (obj instanceof String) {
   ...
   }
}


for (Object o : list) {
    if (o.getClass().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
        handleInt((int)o);
    }
    else if (o.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
        handleString((String)o);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For primitive types you can use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    int arr2[][] = {{1},{2},{3}};
    char arrc[] = {'v', 'c', 'r'};

    System.out.println(arr.getClass().getCanonicalName());      
    System.out.println(arr2.getClass().getCanonicalName());     
    System.out.println(arrc.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

the output is:

```
int[]
int[][]
char[]
```

For ArrayList if you need to work with its elements (if list is not empty) you may check the type of the first element

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arrInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arrInt.add(100);

    if (arrInt instanceof List && arrInt.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(arrInt.get(0).getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
```